# Javascript: Interaction setTimeout() and window.location.assign()

Tags: javascript, location, href, settimeout

I started learning javascript today and don't seem to get a thing with setTimeout() and window.location.assign(*dest*) to work.

Basiclly what I am trying to do is to change the site location after 0.5s and then 0.5s after that change some text with a variable.

```
setTimeout(function foo(){
    window.alert("DID X");
    // document.getElementById("text_element").innerText = "Changed"
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function bar() {
window.location.assign("destination.html"); // on removal both alerts execute
    window.alert("DID Y");                       
}, 500);
```

After playing around I noticed that function foo or bar work if the other is not present.
I also noticed that both alerts trigger when I don't reassign the window location. It seems that changing the site location "swallows" the second setTimeout.

Sadly I haven't found a solution online jet. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: This does not work, because the page reloads and all code loads again. Maybe you're wondering why `alert` is executed although `location.assign` is executed before. This is, because the javascript continues to run and the reload takes some time. The page does no reload as long as the alert popup is open. It freezes the browser until you close it.

Comment: You can try it with hashed based locations and listen to the `onhashchange` event.

Comment: Ah okay thanks. 
Will try it with the eventlistener.

Answer (score 0):

The first line of code executed is: window.location.assign("destination.html");

Once that line of code is run, the rest of your code is skipped because the window changed location and the old window is gone.